# Find out what machines a domain user is logged into

Tags: ssh, debian, login, domain

I know that it is possible to find out what users are currently logged into a Debian Jessie machine, and from which machine they log in (if SSH).
But is there a way, from a Debian Jessie machine, to find out what (Debian Jessie) machines a domain user is currently logged into?